# How to proceed in flyway with failed migration

Tags: spring-boot, flyway

we are having a problem with a failed script of flyway that has been executed in some environments but not in some others.

Let's say we have a Spring Boot service in environments DEV, PRE and PROD and we manage the DB schema with flyway. In DEV we have schema version 5, while in PRE and PROD we have schema version 3. Now, we discover an issue in production and we need a patch to fix it, so we issue schema version 3.1.
In Dev we use the option ignoreIgnoredMigrations as true, so 3.1 will not be applied and flyway will not complain and we set the same idempotent change as version 6 and it works.
Then we deploy version 3.1 in PRE and it works as expected but when we go to PROD with it, the script 3.1 fails and we realized it's not well done and that it will always fail to execute in PROD but it was already executed in PRE. So, I don't know what options have Flyway for this case:

- If we change in any way the script 3.1 to overcome the problem, any version that we try to deploy in PRE will fail since the checksum will be different.
- We can't deploy anything to PRO since script 3.1 will always fail and it won't try to apply a supposed 3.2 with the correct script to execute.

We can set flyway to ignore checksum and just modify script 3.1 so it won't do anything and it will go directly to 3.2 in PROD but that means that we will always have to ignore checksums in the future and we'd like to avoid that.

Is there any way to fix this mess without ignoring errors or checksums forever?

Comment: check repair command: https://flywaydb.org/documentation/command/repair

Comment: Thanks. Finally I went that route. I changed the 3.1 script and provided a Bean implementing FlywayMigrationStrategy which first executes a repair and then a migrate and it works.